# Comment, Uncomment, change setting based on string, add line from terminal

Tags: command-line, server, bash, ssh

I have to edit some files to uncomment a line, change a value on that line or uncomment a line. I am trying to do this
through a bash script.

I am trying to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and change

```
IgnoreRhosts yes
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
```

to

```
IgnoreRhosts no
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
```

and change

```
#PermitRootLogin yes
```

to

```
PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers mroberts
```

and also to edit `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` file in order to change from

```
password sufficient pam_unix.so try_first_pass use_authtok nullok md5
```

to

```
password sufficient pam_unix.so try_first_pass use_authtok nullok md5 shadow
```

I also need to add this line to the `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` file:

```
/etc/pam.d/system-auth file password required pam_unix.so remember=10
```

I have been doing all of this manually using `vi` and I can make the changes through that editor. However, I have to perform this procedure on a lot of hosts and I cannot repeat the process one host at a time. I made a mistake on one where I forgot to add `AllowUsers mroberts` and was locked out of the host for nearly 36 hours.

I'm not sure how to search for a line and change part of it but not the whole line.

Is there a way to make such changes from the terminal or through a bash script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Making many changes all at once

1. Take the original file and save it as `sshd_config.orig`.
2. Edit `sshd_config` to your heart's content.
3. Run

   ```
   diff sshd_config.orig sshd_config >config.patch
   ```

   Keep the `config.patch` file somewhere safe.

Now, anytime that you have a new and unedited version of `sshd_config` and you want to apply the same edits, run:

```
patch sshd_config /path/to/config.patch
```

This will apply the same edits to the new file or warn you if there is some inconsistency that it cannot resolve without your help.

#### Making individual changes

Unix also has powerful command line tools, no editor required, for making changes to files.

Using `sed`, for example:

```
sed -i.bak 's/IgnoreRhosts yes/IgnoreRhosts no/' sshd_config
```

Or, performing the same change with GNU awk:

```
gawk -i inplace '$1=="IgnoreRhosts" {$2="no"} 1' sshd_config
```

The `patch` approach makes it easy to make many changes at once.  For smaller numbers of changes, `sed` and `awk` excel.  To learn more about `sed`, see, for example, [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).  To learn more about `awk`, see, for example, [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Comment: Thanks. Will back it up just in case. I am actually more interested in a way to change things like add/remove a comment or change 'no' to 'yes' or add a line at a particular position. I am looking to these using linux commands rather than making the changes using `vi`.

Comment: If you want to avoid having to use `vi` even just  once, look for a tutorial on `awk` or `sed`.

Comment: That might well be what I am looking for. Do you have an example of its usage for one of these cases?

Comment: `sed -i.bak 's/IgnoreRhosts yes/IgnoreRhosts no/' sshd_config`

Comment: @WR I have updated the answer with info on sed and awk to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Those tutorials are exactly what I was after. is there any preference between `grep`, `awk` and `sed` for these particular tasks?

Comment: `grep` is for selecting, not editing.  `sed` is good for substitutions using regular expressions.  `awk` is good for things where the input can be divided into records (default:lines) and fields (default: space-separated columns).